# Onmouseover is not working in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, marquee

Hi I am showing items from library to the main page using Content Query. TO scroll this items i am using Marquee now i want to stop when OnMouseOver and again start on out i use onmouseover="stop()" onmouseout="start()" and button to stop but its not working please is the code i have. Can anyone help how use or is there any option. Thank you.

```
 <marquee id="test" bgcolor="rgba(235,235,235,0.8)" scrolldelay="10" direction="up" scrollamount="2" style="width: 435px; height: 252px;">
<div>
   <div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" contenteditable="false">
     <div class="ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read 7678e8de-25e2-420f-a052-a9ae8bd6a173" id="div_7678e8de-25e2-420f-a052-a9ae8bd6a173" unselectable="on">
      </div>
      <div id="vid_7678e8de-25e2-420f-a052-a9ae8bd6a173" unselectable="on" style="display: none;">
       </div>
     </div> 
     <style>
#WebPartWPQ2 a {
color:#000000 !important;
}
</style></div></marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, if I understand you correctly, you would like to add a MouseOver and MouseOut effect to a marquee. If that is correct. all you needed to do is tell the browser that you wanted **THIS** marquee and it would have worked. your code right now does not say which marquee you want the JavaScript to work towards.

**syntax =** *some-event="*(What)***Target****.***(Which)***action***();"

**this**.stop(); or **this**.start

onMouseOver="this.stop();"

> Hope this is what you were looking for. If not could you rephrase your
>   question. I had a hard time understanding you.

```html
<style>
  #WebPartWPQ2 a {
    color: #000000 !important;
  }
</style>
<marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" id="test" bgcolor="rgba(235,235,235,0.8)" scrolldelay="10" direction="up" scrollamount="2" style="width: 435px; height: 252px;">
  <div>
    <div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" contenteditable="false">
      <div class="ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read 7678e8de-25e2-420f-a052-a9ae8bd6a173" id="div_7678e8de-25e2-420f-a052-a9ae8bd6a173" unselectable="on">
      </div>
      <div id="vid_7678e8de-25e2-420f-a052-a9ae8bd6a173" unselectable="on" style="display: none;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</marquee>
```